# Which role pays the most?

Tags: red-dead-online

I've been playing red dead online for a couple of months. I recently got my bounty hunter role and was able to make 1000$ in about 4 days. I'm saving up for the prestigious bounty hunter license, but I'm also wondering whether or  not I should buy a different role. Being a bounty hunter is probably one of the most fun roles to play, but does it pay the most? I've seen collectors getting around 300$ or 200$ when they complete a collection. That was a long time ago though, and I don't know if the prices of the collections have gone down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to GamersDecide on the website found [here](https://www.gamersdecide.com/articles/red-dead-online-roles),

> The Moonshiner Role is the most recent of the Player Roles added to
> Red Dead Online, and while it is the most expensive one to start, it
> can also be **by far the most profitable** of the four choices. In
> addition to making a lot of money, the Moonshiner role offers a better
> variety of mission types and activities.

This role pays very well if done right, and offers many interesting missions and special offers. It also offers the most money per sale.